# Multiple contexts pointing to a single webapp

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications

Is there anyway of configuring tomcat to point more than one context at a webapp?

I need to point these two urls:

http://server.com/abc
http://server.com/def

to a webapp running under the context `abc`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tomcat does not allow direct configuring of multiple `<Context>` elements to point to the same path.

So your options are either deploying the same web app twice with different `Context` (Not great idea)

or create a webapp called `def` that has one custom servlet filter declared in the web.xml that re-writes all requests to `abc`.

Answer (score 2):

If your requirement is for a production app, I would recommend having an Apache Web Server before the tomcat so that you can do this and more.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this isn't a possibility for us.

Comment: Have you checked Virtual Hosting with Tomcat : http://www.ex-parrot.com/pete/tomcat-vhost.html

Comment: That looks promising... Can you give me an example usage with my scenario? It looks more like many urls to many contexts to me :s